# Generic function, which populates a collection based on collection interface implementation

Tags: c#, generics

As the above title states I have a function that I use to populate a collection's status names, currency names and other information that I do not store in the database.

This is my function:

```
    public static List<T> PopulateStatusNames<T>(List<T> items) where T : class
    {

        if (typeof(IStatusResult).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> statuses = new Dictionary<int, string>();

            if (typeof(IActivityStatusResult).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))) statuses = GlobalConstants.GetActivityStatuses();
            if (typeof(IPurchaseStatusResult).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))) statuses = GlobalConstants.GetPurchaseStatuses();
            if (typeof(IQuotationStatusResult).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))) statuses = GlobalConstants.GetQuotationStatuses();
            if (typeof(IInvoiceStatusResult).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))) statuses = GlobalConstants.GetInvoiceStatuses();

            foreach (var item in items.OfType<IStatusResult>())
            {
                item.StatusName = statuses[item.Status];
            }
        }

        if (typeof(ICurrencyResult).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> currencies = GlobalConstants.GetCurrencies();

            foreach (var item in items.OfType<ICurrencyResult>())
            {
                item.CurrencyName = currencies[item.Currency];
            }
        }

        return items;
    }
```

So if a collection implements an interface of type IStatusResult I look up the approapriate status names and loop through the collection to set the status name.

As you also notice in the above that I loop through my collection twice because if  my collection implements another type of interface I need to get a different set key value pairs so that I can look up the name

Is there a way to re-write the below function to populate status names, currency names in a single for loop

Sample POCO that implement these interfaces

Invoice:

```
public class InvoiceSearchResult : IInvoiceStatusResult, ICurrencyResult
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
    public string Project { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public int Currency { get; set; }
    public string CurrencyName { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string StatusName { get; set; }
    public decimal Subtotal { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalTax { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

Location:

```
public class LocationSearchResult : IActivityStatusResult
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string StatusName { get; set; }
}
```

So as you can see I have a different combination of collections that implement these interfaces, based on the interfaces I am trying to figure out what needs to be populated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely there is actually four loops in your code. Two is explicit and other two from code like `items.OfType<IStatusResult>()` where if you look at the implementation of `OfType<T>` is looks something like below

```
foreach (object obj in source)
      {
        if (obj is TResult)
          yield return (TResult) obj;
      }
```

I would rather prefer to have one foreach loop to loop through all the items once and based on the type of each item, assign the appropriate properties something like below

```
foreach (var item in items)
            {
                if (typeof(ICurrencyResult).IsAssignableFrom(item.GetType()))
                {
                    item.CurrencyName = currencies[item.Currency];
                }
                else if (typeof(IStatusResult).IsAssignableFrom(item.GetType()))
                {
                    item.StatusName = statuses[item.Status];
                }
            }
```

Comment: i am not sure if that is going to work, will test it though. Without the implicit `OfType<IStatusResult>()` i was failing to access the Status and StatusName properties in the loop

Comment: If you have actual instances then rather than calling `GetType()` and `IsAssignableFrom` you can just test `is`. As a bonus, with recent language versions you can do the coercion which gives you the ability to set the property: `if (item is CurrencyResult currencyResult) currencyResult.CurrencyName = currencies[currencyResult.Currency];` But this still has some ugliness in fetching the status lookup, and it's pretty much guaranteed to do wasted work on type checks whose results should be known at compile-time.

Comment: @JustLearning you can access StatusName property by casting it to be of type interface like ((IStatusResult)item).StatusName. assuming statusname is a property of IStatusResult.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh. Not only does this effectively push method resolution to runtime rather than compile-time, but it doesn't handle ambiguities. What if someone foolishly implements `IActivityStatusResult` and `IPurchaseStatusResult` in the same class?

I would consider handling this with T4 code generation. Something like

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ output extension=".g.cs" #>
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Foo
{
    public static partial class Bar
    {
<# WritePopulateStatusNames("IActivityStatusResult",  "GlobalConstants.GetActivityStatuses()",  "Status",   "StatusName"); #>
<# WritePopulateStatusNames("IPurchaseStatusResult",  "GlobalConstants.GetPurchaseStatuses()",  "Status",   "StatusName"); #>
<# WritePopulateStatusNames("IQuotationStatusResult", "GlobalConstants.GetQuotationStatuses()", "Status",   "StatusName"); #>
<# WritePopulateStatusNames("IInvoiceStatusResult",   "GlobalConstants.GetInvoiceStatuses()",   "Status",   "StatusName"); #>
<# WritePopulateStatusNames("ICurrencyResult",        "GlobalConstants.GetCurrencies()",        "Currency", "CurrencyName"); #>
    }
}

<#+ public void WritePopulateStatusNames(string type, string dict, string intProp, string strProp)
    {
#>      public static List<<#=type#>> PopulateStatusNames(List<<#=type#>> items)
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> lookup = <#=dict#>;

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                item.<#=strProp#> = lookup[item.<#=intProp#>];
            }

            return items;
        }

<#+ }#>
```

That way you get compile-time resolution and a compile-time error in case of ambiguities.

---

On the actual code itself, why `List<>`? Code to the interface, not the implementation: here that means preferring `IList<>` or even `IEnumerable<>`.